# Counting Problem (4 Digit Code) - Equality

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have that the number of 4 digit codes (each can be 0-9) is $10^4$.

I know that the number of 4 digit codes with no repeats is $P(10,4)$.

I figured that (the total number of 4 digit codes) - (4 digit codes with no repeats) should equal

(4 digit codes with 3 repeats) : 10

$+$

(4 digit codes with 2 repeats) : ${4\choose 3} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 = 360$

$+$

(4 digit codes with 1 repeats) : ${4\choose 2} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8= 4320$

but

$4690 \neq 4960$

My brain is going to explode. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed $\overline{AABB},\overline{ABAB}$, $\overline{ABBA}$ etc which contains $${4\choose 2} \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot\frac{1}{2}=270$$ cases, and $4690 + 270 = 4960$.